# How can i store a lot of images in asp.net

Tags: asp.net, image, store

I have a lot of images (more than 8TB, and they become more every day) and I want to organize them in groups in asp.net
In fact I want to create an archive program for my images.
How can I store them in different HDD?

Answer (score 0):

You can make a configraton that makes each group Read from defirent path for example

If you have 8 HD each one 2 TB you will have 8 paths and you can map them for 8 groups or more

Group 1 >> `D:\images`

Group 1 >> `E:\images`

Group 1 >> `F:\images`